# Update row based on calculation of previous row - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, updating

I want to update the whole table (shown in the picture) per id. As it shown in the picture I need to calculate value for columns in each row for each `user_id` :

```
interim balance = opening_balance + Debit+ Credit 

calculated_interest = (opening_balance + Debit+ Credit) * interest_rate

closing_balance = interim balance  + calculated_interest
```

The `opening_balance` for each row is the `closing_balance` from the previous row. Therefore, the `opening_balance` for the next row depends on calculation of the previous row.

I have tried to using lagging but since the calculation for previous row is not done, all values become 0.

Here is the code I have tried and it is not working.

```
UPDATE M
SET M.closing_balance = res.closing_balance + res.Credit + res.Debit
FROM [Test].[dbo].[Main] M
JOIN
    (SELECT
         a.[User_ID], a.[calender_day],  a.[Debit], a.[Credit], 
         LAG(closing_balance, 1, (a.[opening_balance] + a.[Debit] + a.[Credit])) OVER (PARTITION BY [User_ID] ORDER BY [calender_day] ASC) AS closing_balance
     FROM 
         [Test].[dbo].[Main] a) res ON res.[User_ID] = M.User_ID
                                    AND res.[calender_day] = M.[calender_day]
```

[image]

Comment: The query you tried seems to be attempting to update the value of `closing_balance`, but your question seems to be asking to set the value of `opening_balance`.   Which is it?

Comment: Yes, since it has to wait for closing balance of previous row, I think lagging might not work. Is there any way to do the calculation and update next row?

Comment: Well it would be easy to do with loop.  Maybe a recursive CTE would also work?

Comment: It is 132404813 rows, I think it would take a long time. Can I do it sequential but in parallel for each user_id?

Comment: what sql server version are you using?

Comment: I am using ms sql server 2017, developer edition.

Comment: You wouldn't be able to automate a parallel implementation, (at least not purely in TSQL) but you could do it manually.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer to my question that found.

```
    FIRST_VALUE(openingbalance) OVER 
(PARTITION BY UserID ORDER BY Calendar_day ) + 
SUM(Credit - Debit) OVER 
(PARTITION BY UserID ORDER BY Calendar_day ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)
```

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this will be any faster than looping, but you can do this by instead of LAG, calculating each row based on all the rows that came before it.

A quick idea of what I mean is:

```
OpeningBalance=(Subquery to get The First OpeningBalance for this UserID)
 + SUM(Debit) + SUM(Credit) WHERE CalendarDay < {This Row's CalendarDay}

ClosingBalance=(Subquery to get The First OpeningBalance for this UserID)
 + SUM(Debit) + SUM(Credit) WHERE CalendarDay <= {This Row's CalendarDay}
```

Comment: Someone else suggested me to do the calculation like this, which is working.

FIRST_VALUE(openingbalance) OVER (PARTITION BY UserID ORDER BY Calendar_day ) + SUM(Credit - Debit) OVER (PARTITION BY UserID ORDER BY Calendar_day ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)

Answer (score 0):

Run update in CLR using RW cursor on recordset ordered by user_id and calendar_day. CLR can be aggregate and calculate data and update with a single table scan.